# JavaScript touch event updates for force or radius

Tags: javascript, events, touch, dom-events

JavaScript touch events contain properties for radius and force. Unfortunately it appears that events aren't generated when either property changes. Events are only triggered for things like touch start, move or end. Can anyone think of a way to get more updates on change of touch size?

Currently to get radius updates I have to wiggle my finger to trigger the touch move event, but I would prefer a software solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and then discovered this blog post: http://blog.framerjs.com/posts/prototyping-3D-touch-interactions.html

In a nutshell, we need to use `touchstart` event to capture the touch event, assign the event to a variable and then use `setInterval` to get the `force` value:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myElement');
var currTouch = null;
var currTouchInterval = null;

attachListeners = function () {
    el.addEventListener('touchstart', enterForceTouch, false);
    el.addEventListener('touchend', exitForceTouch, false);
}

enterForceTouch = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    currTouch = evt;
    currTouchInterval = setInterval(updateForceTouch, 10); // 100 times per second.
}

updateForceTouch = function() {
    if (currTouch) {
        console.log(currTouch.touches[0].force); // Log our current force value.
    }
}

exitForceTouch = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    currTouch = null;
    clearInterval(currTouchInterval);
}

attachListeners();
```

Comment: Sadly this (setInterval method) didn't work with the Asus tablet that we tested on. Looks like it still needs touchmove to fire in order to update the values like force or radiusX, radiusY.

Answer (score 0):

Related discussion:
[How to get touchstart to update touch.radiusX constantly? ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170932/how-to-get-touchstart-to-update-touch-radiusx-constantly-es6/75669674#75669674)

Fortunately there is a better way with the new `pointerrawupdate` event by which you can use `event.width` instead of `radiusX` to detect how fat the user's finger is. Just tested on Android/Chrome and it fires about 50% more frequently when compared to `touchmove`. The result could be good enough in certain applications.

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_pointerrawupdate_event