# How to get touchstart to update touch.radiusX constantly? ES6

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ecmascript-6

I have tried everything to get `touchstart` to update `touch.radiusX` constantly… yet nothing is working.

> For some reason **setInterval** doesn't work.

**What I'm trying to achieve**
I'm trying to simulate `force touch` through a constant update of `touch.radiusX` while `touchstart` is active.



**Heads Up**
This is for website buttons.
Yes I know about `touch.force` 
But I do not want `touch.force` due to it not working on android.


**What I know**
I know that `touch.radiusX` is supported on both `android` and `iOS`.
So basically if I can get a constant update of `touch.radiusX` while `touchstart`
I can simulate `force.touch` on both platforms.

**What I have**
At the moment I can get the `touch.radiusX`.
But only once per `touchstart`.
I need it to be constantly while user is `touching` element.

## How it should look

`On touchstart`
`every X-milliseconds`
`element.innerHTML = touch.radiusX`
`On touchend` `reset to 0`

```js
var src = document.getElementById("myElement");
src.addEventListener('touchstart', rotate);

function rotate(e) {
  var touch = e.changedTouches.item(0);
  e.preventDefault();
  src.innerHTML = touch.radiusX
};
```

```html
<div id="myElement" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #f5f5f5; position: fixed;">

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and add the appropiate tags to it. Cause ppl that just see Javascript, like me, have absolutely no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: This is javascript… it's pure javascript ES6

Comment: There are no libraries attached to it.

Comment: No it isn't. You're clearly talking about Android and iOS. You're most likely talking about a mobile app or website. So add the appropiate tags "android" and "iOS" and "ecmascript-6"

Comment: Thanks. Now ppl like me that have very little knowledge about ES6 can avoid the question and ppl that do know about it are more likely to check your question. It's a win-win :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have to use touch events only, the best possible thing (though still not good enough) is updating `radiusX` and/or `radiusY` every time `touchmove` fires .

But there is a better way with the new `pointerrawupdate` event by which you can use `event.width` instead of `radiusX` to detect how fat the user's finger is. Just tested on Android/Chrome and it fires about 50% more frequently when compared to `touchmove`. The result could be good enough in certain applications.

https://chromestatus.com/feature/6041426311774208

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_pointerrawupdate_event

Answer (score -1):

This may work assuming the radiusX is updated to changes:

```
var src = document.getElementById("myElement");
src.addEventListener('touchstart', rotate, true);

function rotate(e) {
var touch = e.changedTouches.item(0);
e.preventDefault();
setTimeout(function detect(){
src.innerHTML = touch.radiusX;
if(touch. .radiusX===0){return; };
detect();
}, 16);
};
<div id="myElement" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #f5f5f5; position: fixed;">

</div>
```

Comment: It failed to work. It's doing that same as before… it just updates once.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a limitation of radiusX or not.